# Вывод таблицы на новую вкладку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть проблемы с написанием скрипта, который выводит таблицу с именами людей, год рождения - случайное число 1900 - 2016, а вес 3 - 150.

**Необходимо чтобы таблица выводилась на отдельную вкладку браузера**. Надо чтобы была функция, которая строит таблицу,а потом при создании window.open() вызывалась эта функция? Понимаю, будет звучать нагло, но подкорректируйте мой код.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "windows - 1251">
<title>Таблица имен</title>
<style>
table {
width: 50%;
border: 3px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: auto;
}
td, th {
padding: 2px;
border: solid black;
}
th {
background: deepskyblue;
}
.center {
text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:hover {
background: cyan;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>   
<script>
function randomValue(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
amount = +prompt("Введите количество полей:");
   document.write ('<p align = "center" style = "font-size: 30px">Таблица персональных даних</p>');
   document.write ('<table>');
   document.writeln('<tr> <th>№<\/th><th>Ф.И.О.<\/th><th>Год рождения<\/th><th>Вес<\/th> <\/tr>');
   for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
           var name = prompt("Введите Ф.И.О." + (i + 1) +" - го человека");
           if (name.trim() == ""){
           do {
                name =  prompt("Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте еще раз:")
            } while (name.trim() == "");}
          document.writeln('<tr class = "center">');
              document.writeln('<td>' + (i + 1) + '<\/td>');
              document.writeln('<td>' + name + '<\/td>');
              document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(1900, 2016) + '<\/td>');
              document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(3, 150) + '<\/td>');
           document.writeln('<\/tr>');     
     }
    document.write ('</table>');
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: а откуда данные то берутся?

Comment: а в чем вопрос заключается?

Comment: Какие данные? Вы имеете в виду имена и количество строк? Они ведь вводятся через prompt. А просил я помощи в редактировании кода

Comment: а что отредактировать-то надо? _В чем проблема понять не могу_ - никто не сможет :-) вы ж не написали **какую** проблему вы видите в вашем коде

Comment: я сам не знаю, он просто не работает

Comment: как именно не работает? выдаешь ошибку? ошибку в консоли? ничего не выдает? выдает что-то неожиданное?

Comment: запускаю файл c кодом, а в браузере открываеться пустая страница. Тип файла .html

Comment: разве не так надо запускать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40213/discussion-between-grundy-and-muscled-boy).

Comment: Это так сложно или меня прост игнорят?  Да, со стороны может показаться,что я просто требую код, но поверьте мне на слово, если бы я мог сделать его сам, конкурс за этот вопрос не создавал бы.

Comment: Просто Вы не можете сказать, что именно Вам нужно. В чем заключается суть вопроса. Сделать запись в отдельный документ, который открыть в отдельной вкладке? Не возможно сделать и скрипт заполнения (с авто-вызовом) и показ таблицы из одной страницы в разных вкладках. Тут непонимание сути на лицо. 

Подозреваю, что можно решить этот вопрос еще добавив кнопку "Добавить записи", которая будет вызывать функцию со всеми document.write

Comment: Откуда вообще взялось это требование? первоисточник задания укажи, как оно звучит на самом деле

Comment: так и звучит.а первоисточник - методичка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого вам нужно?

```html
<script>
  function randomValue(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
amount = +prompt("Введите количество полей:");

var wnd = window.open('#','_blank');

   wnd.document.write ('<html>');
   wnd.document.write ('<head>');
   wnd.document.write ('<title></title>');
   wnd.document.write ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablestyle.css">'); 
   wnd.document.write ('</head>');
   wnd.document.write ('<body>');

   wnd.document.write ('<p align = "center" style = "font-size: 30px">Таблица персональных даних</p>');
   wnd.document.write ('<table>');
   wnd.document.writeln('<tr> <th>№<\/th><th>Ф.И.О.<\/th><th>Год рождения<\/th><th>Вес<\/th> <\/tr>');
   for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
       var name = prompt("Введите Ф.И.О." + (i + 1) +" - го человека");
       if (name.trim() == ""){
       do {
            name =  prompt("Вы ничего не ввели. Попробуйте еще раз:")
        } while (name.trim() == "");}
      wnd.document.writeln('<tr class = "center">');
          wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + (i + 1) + '<\/td>');
          wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + name + '<\/td>');
          wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(1900, 2016) + '<\/td>');
          wnd.document.writeln('<td>' + randomValue(3, 150) + '<\/td>');
       wnd.document.writeln('<\/tr>');     
 }
wnd.document.write ('</table>');
wnd.document.write ('</body>');
wnd.document.write ('</html>');
  </script>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40768/discussion-on-answer-by-akainq-----).